# Listview - How does Explorer get the same size for all items in Small Icons view?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, winapi, listview

I have an app using ListView not unlike Explorer does, but when I set the ListView to SmallIcon view my items are not stacked in neat columns as they are in Explorer; they get scattered around, and it seems to depend on how long the text label is.

Also, when I set it to List view, the default size for the items is too small, so my labels get cropped.

I can't for the life of me spot how to force Listview to use a fixed size, or to specify what that size is, for each listview item.  I'm in C# WinForms but I'd be happy with a Win32 solution.

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: Hmm. I think this belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: What styles do you create the control with? How do you add the items? Way too little info here to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, the current (Win7) explorer isn't technically a listview, it's a custom control, or so I'm told.

Furthermore, items within a listview are positioned, so the solution to this probably involves setting the x/y position of each item as you add them to the listview.